# Operator string 'array_contains' is invalid

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python (firebase_admin) package to run a script to fill my firestore database with data.

And when I run this following query:

```
search_releases = self.db.collection('new_search')
  .where(u'm_y_filters', u'array_contains', month_year).get()
```

I get this following error:

> ValueError: Operator string 'array_contains' is invalid. Valid choices are: <, <=, ==, >, >=.

Why is this? Is there something wrong with array_contains nor array-contains works? Why is this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely using an old version of the SDK.  The Firebase Admin SDK just delegates to the google-cloud-python package.  You can see from the release notes that array_contains was supported starting with [google-cloud-python version 0.31.0](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/releases/tag/firestore-0.31.0) three months ago.  The feature request was [tracked here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6479).  Make sure you are using the latest of everything.